# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'team_members' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I am getting the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'team_members' referenced before
>   assignment

Slug values in my model by default are 1.

This is the function:

```
def single_slug(request, single_slug):

team = [c.infraTeam_slug for c in infraTeam.objects.all()]
if single_slug in team:
   team_members = TeamMember.objects.filter(infra_team__infraTeam_slug=single_slug)
   series_urls = {}

for m in team_members.all():
    part_one = vulnerability.objects.filter(member_name__member_name=m.member_name).earliest("vulnerabilty_date")
    series_urls[m] = part_one.vulnerability_slug

return render(request=request,
              template_name='main/category.html',
              context={"member_name": team_members, "part_ones": series_urls})
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If the `if` *not* satisfied, then `team_member`s is not assigned.

Comment: You get that error when `single_slug` is not in `team`. You have to assign a value to `team_members` in that case with an `else` clause.

Comment: single_slug does exist i have verified through this   if single_slug in team:
      return HttpResponse(f"{single_slug} is a team") i do get value for single_slug only when i am trying to pass it to variable its not happening